# Is it really necessary that Stack Exchange functionality depends on Google?

Tags: discussion

For reasons of personal data security I prefer to disallow Google scripts outside Google domain.

With domain ajax.googleapis.com disabled, I can still read Stack Exchange sites, but can't interact with them (asking or answering questions, voting, commenting).

I understand the convenience for SE developers, the importance of SE playing well with Google Search, and the fact that SE comunities are not that worse off without my so far negligible input. But I believe that other members of community open to [various aspects of Google activities](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=google%20spying) would, too, welcome a neutral, Google-free Q-A environment.

[image: Warning about missing functionality]

[image: list of blocked sources]

Comment: Yes, it is really necessary.

Comment: It's also necessary because all Google domains are blocked in China.

Comment: By any chance, are you unable to take these actions because you created you SE site accounts by logging in with Google?

Comment: @user30031 No, I have a regular account in that I have a username and a password I use solely for Stack Exchange sites and usethe plain old login form here. I did register with a Gmail e-mail address, but if that was the problem, it would raise more questions.